# New line errors in FontForge

Tags: fonts, font-forge

I've been creating a fictional, Arabic-inspired font in FontForge using a Latin keyboard. I've only been able to get initial contextual substitutions to work by starting each line with a space.

This has led to many errors when I am bumped down a line. I have tried creating and include the NewLine characters in my font's contextual substitutions, but it hasn't had any effect.